# spring boot mvc downloding file instead of resolving jsp

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have written a simple `spring boot mvc application` with jsp as view resolver.

Cofiguration inside application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

There is a jsp file with the name returned from the `Controller`

Inside pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I hit the controller, instead of displaying the jsp page, its getting downloaded as file. If I configure the internal resolver to .html, its working. But when I try to use the jsp extension, it's not working.

Spring Boot does a lot of magic out of box. But in situations like these, How to know the list of jars registered in the container? Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: But this was working sometime ago.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I was using ControllerAdvice over an Exception class earlier. I removed that annotation and started the container. It is working now. I againg uncommented the ControllerAdvice and now it started working again. Strange.